# Как продолжить работу в командной строке после запуска sh-скрипта?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

Вот небольшой пример:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -x 21236.pts-0.194-67-90-155
```

в этом окне открыт файл через nano, и получается, что после определенного запроса в нем должно меняться содержимое строки, соответственно я не понимаю как можно автоматически ее там заменить.

Если прописать следующую строку в bash скрипте, то он ее пытается выполнять в консоли с которой я переходил в screen.

Как такое решить?

Comment: а как вы делаете то, что вам надо (абсолютно, кстати, непонятно, что именно), без участия программы screen?

Comment: я вообще ничего не понял

Answer (score 1):

> я не понимаю как можно автоматически ее там заменить.

Некоторые программы просмотра/редактирования делают это сами. Например, если во время просмотра  pdf файла программой *okular* изменить этот  файл, то изменения сразу же отобразятся в окне просмотра.

Однако *nano* - слишком простой редактор и я сомневаюсь, что он так умеет делать.

Существует общая методика обработки таких задач:

1. С помощью *inotify* задаём отслеживание изменений файла, который потом будет показываться в *nano* (См: https://mnorin.com/inotify-v-bash.html)
2. Запускаем *nano* на этот файл
3. Получив сигнал об изменении файла, прибиваем *nano* и запускаем его по новой.

Но всё это как-то не очень красиво... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите смотреть какие изменения произошли в файле, то вот варианты.

1. Через команду `tail -f файл` можно отслеживать запись в конец файла
2. `watch -n1 cat файл` будет выводить содержимое всего файла на консоль каждую секунду, обновляя весь экран
3. Если файл большой, то можно указать номера строк `watch -n1 "awk 'NR >= 2 && NR <= 4' файл"` - будут печататься строки 2-4 каждую секунду.
4. `watch -n1 "diff файл файл.old"` - наблюдение за различиями текущего файла и его прошлой версии
5. Если умеете пользоваться git, то можно попробовать `watch -n1 "git diff"`

`nano` следить за изменениями в файле не умеет